# How to Create a Downloadable Product through Magento API?

Tags: php, api, soap, magento

I am new to Magento, and are using their API. 
What I want to ask, is it possible to create a downloadable product through the API? 
The documentation example is just for creating a new simple product, and if I use the API to view the product.info of a downloadable product, I don't see any attribute that link to a downloadable file assigned to that product.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation now is good enough for learn about Magento SOAP API V1.

Create a product from SOAP API V1 like the example :

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$filesPath = '/var/www/ws/tests/WebService/etc/Modules/Downloadable/Product/Link';
$downloadableProductId = 'downloadable_demo_product';

$items = array(
    'small' => array(
        'link' => array(
            'title' => 'Test file',
            'price' => '123',
            'is_unlimited' => '1',
            'number_of_downloads' => '111',
            'is_shareable' => '0',
            'sample' => array(
                'type' => 'file',
                'file' =>
                array(
                    'filename' => 'files/test.txt',
                ),
                'url' => 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/img/logo.gif',
            ),
            'type' => 'file',
            'file' =>
            array(
                'filename' => 'files/test.txt',
            ),
            'link_url' => 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/img/logo.gif',
        ),
        'sample' => array(
            'title' => 'Test sample file',
            'type' => 'file',
            'file' => array(
                'filename' => 'files/image.jpg',
            ),
            'sample_url' => 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/img/logo.gif',
            'sort_order' => '3',
        )
    ),
    'big' => array(
        'link' => array(
            'title' => 'Test url',
            'price' => '123',
            'is_unlimited' => '0',
            'number_of_downloads' => '111',
            'is_shareable' => '1',
            'sample' => array(
                'type' => 'url',
                'file' => array(
                    'filename' => 'files/book.pdf',
                ),
                'url' => 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/img/logo.gif',
            ),
            'type' => 'url',
            'file' => array(
                'filename' => 'files/song.mp3',
            ),
            'link_url' => 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/img/logo.gif',
        ),
        'sample' => array(
            'title' => 'Test sample url',
            'type' => 'url',
            'file' => array(
                'filename' => 'files/image.jpg',
            ),
            'sample_url' => 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/img/logo.gif',
            'sort_order' => '3',
        )
    )
);

$result = true;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['type'] == 'file') {
            $filePath = $filesPath . '/' . $value['file']['filename'];
            $value['file'] = array('name' => str_replace('/', '_', $value['file']['filename']), 'base64_content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath)), 'type' => $value['type']);
        }
        if ($value['sample']['type'] == 'file') {
            $filePath = $filesPath . '/' . $value['sample']['file']['filename'];
            $value['sample']['file'] = array('name' => str_replace('/', '_', $value['sample']['file']['filename']), 'base64_content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath)));
        }
        if (!$proxy->call(
            $sessionId,
            'product_downloadable_link.add',
            array($downloadableProductId, $value, $key)
        )
        ) {
            $result = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[source link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductDownloadableLink/catalogProductDownloadableLink.html)

and you can add custom attribute

[from here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/catalogProductAttribute.html)

Answer (score 0):

we all are new to Magento as the documentation is very scarce and incomplete.

I advice you to take a look into this method : [setTypeInstance](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.html#setTypeInstance) from the Product model.
and into this class [Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Type](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Downloadable/Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Type.html).

As you are creating the product through the API, the only issue is to find the correct format to put this data into the productData array that is required by the API. Probably in your array you'll need something like this:

```
// this is speculation
"type" => "downloadable",
"download_path" => "url"
```